# Getting Row Count by SubQuery which has GROUP BY - MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery

I currently have a table with following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `order_handling` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `oh_no` varchar(24) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL, 
  `date_request` datetime DEFAULT NULL, 
  `status` smallint(4) DEFAULT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

I want to perform query that will result like this:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| MonthDone | OhProgress | OhHold | OhCancel | OhDone | Total |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| June 2016 |          2 |      1 |        1 |      3 |     7 |
| July 2016 |          6 |      1 |     null |   null |     7 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

My Query is,

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(`oh`.`date_request`, '%m-%Y') AS `IdMonth`,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM order_handling as oh1 WHERE `oh1`.`status` IN (1,2) GROUP BY IdMonth) As OhProgress,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM order_handling as oh2 WHERE `oh2`.`status` IN (3) GROUP BY IdMonth) As OhHold,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM order_handling as oh3 WHERE `oh3`.`status` IN (4) GROUP BY IdMonth) As OhCancel,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM order_handling as oh3 WHERE `oh3`.`status` IN (5) GROUP BY IdMonth) As OhDone,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM order_handling as oh5 WHERE `oh5`.`status` IN (1,2,3,4,5) GROUP BY IdMonth) As SumTotal
FROM `order_handling` `oh`
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`oh`.`date_request`, '%M %Y')
ORDER BY `oh`.`date_request` ASC
```

The output was not expected. If I change SubQuery GROUP BY with `DATE_FORMAT(date_request, '%m-%Y')` like follows:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(`oh`.`date_request`, '%m-%Y') AS `IdMonth`,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM order_handling as oh1 WHERE `oh1`.`status` IN (1,2) GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`oh1`.`date_request`, '%m-%Y')) As OhProgress,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM order_handling as oh2 WHERE `oh2`.`status` IN (3) GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`oh2`.`date_request`, '%m-%Y')) As OhHold,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM order_handling as oh3 WHERE `oh3`.`status` IN (4) GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`oh3`.`date_request`, '%m-%Y')) As OhCancel,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM order_handling as oh4 WHERE `oh4`.`status` IN (5) GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`oh4`.`date_request`, '%m-%Y')) As OhDone,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM order_handling as oh5 WHERE `oh5`.`status` IN (1,2,3,4,5) GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`oh5`.`date_request`, '%m-%Y')) As SumTotal
FROM `order_handling` `oh`
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`oh`.`date_request`, '%M %Y')
ORDER BY `oh`.`date_request` ASC
```

It gives me Error: **Subquery return more than 1 row**
Here is my [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0fcd22/22)

Please help,
thank you

Comment: Are you looking for this query? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0fcd22/38

Comment: @Mihai yes, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(oh.`date_request`, '%m-%Y') AS `IdMonth`,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM order_handling as oh1 
     WHERE oh1.`status` IN (1,2) AND 
           `IdMonth` = DATE_FORMAT(oh1.`date_request`, '%m-%Y')) As OhProgress,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM order_handling as oh2 
     WHERE oh2.`status` IN (3) AND 
           `IdMonth` = DATE_FORMAT(oh2.`date_request`, '%m-%Y')) As OhHold,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM order_handling as oh3 
     WHERE oh3.`status` IN (4) AND 
           `IdMonth` = DATE_FORMAT(oh3.`date_request`, '%m-%Y')) As OhCancel,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM order_handling as oh4 
     WHERE oh4.`status` IN (5) AND 
           `IdMonth` = DATE_FORMAT(oh4.`date_request`, '%m-%Y')) As OhDone,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM order_handling as oh5 
     WHERE oh5.`status` IN (1,2,3,4,5) AND 
           `IdMonth` = DATE_FORMAT(oh5.`date_request`, '%m-%Y')) As SumTotal
FROM `order_handling` oh
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(oh.`date_request`, '%M %Y')
ORDER BY oh.`date_request` ASC
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0fcd22/41)

Answer (score 4):

No need for subqueries

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(`date_request`, '%m-%Y') AS `IdMonth`,
   SUM(status IN (1,2) ) As OhProgress,
    SUM(status IN (3) ) As OhHold,
    SUM(status IN (4) ) As OhCancel,
    SUM(status IN (5) ) As OhDone,
    SUM(status IN (1,2,3,4,5)) As SumTotal
FROM `order_handling` 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`date_request`, '%M %Y')
ORDER BY `date_request` ASC
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0fcd22/38) (courtesy of @Giorgos)